# Show that $\frac{x \phi(x)}{2 \Phi(x) - 1}$ is decreasing for $x \geq 0$.

Tags: inequality, gaussian

I am looking to prove that the following function $G: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is decreasing over it's domain:

$$G(x) := \frac{x \phi(x)}{2 \Phi(x) - 1}$$ for $x \geq 0$. Here $\phi(x)$, and $\Phi(x)$ denote the PDF, and CDF (respectively) of a $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ random variable. As noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4359553/upper-bound-for-standard-normal-fracx-phix2-phix-1), $G(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ by L'Hospital's rule.

Based on numerical plots, it does appear to be decreasing for all $x \in [0, \infty)$. Formally, I tried showing that $G^{\prime}(x) \leq 0$, but got the following complicated expression for $G^{\prime}(x)$:

\begin{equation}
   G^{\prime}(x) = \frac{(2 \Phi(x) - 1)(\phi(x) + x \phi^{\prime}(x)) - 2 x \phi^{2}(x)}{(2 \Phi(x) - 1)^{2}}
\end{equation}

but I wasn't able to show this is non-negative. Could anyone please show how to obtain this using elementary methods and properties of the standard normal random variable?

Comment: @user170231 - thanks. One clarification, I have corrected my formula for $G^{\prime}(x)$, it had an issue in the numerator. For your question, for all $x \geq 0$, we have $\frac{1}{2} \leq \Phi(x) \leq 1 \iff 0 \leq 2 \Phi(x) - 1 \leq 1$, so the sign is non-negative over our domain of $G(x)$. Given the numerator has been edited, I'm not sure how to conclude $G^{\prime}(x)$ is negative for all $x \geq 0$. Any ideas how to show this?

Comment: Ignore my comment... it's not actually true that $\phi+x\phi'\ge0$; in fact it's negative for $x>1$.

Comment: Similarities with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1707981/305862) but for a $\color{red}{log}$normal distribution

Comment: I'm not sure what your difficulty is. Expressing everything in terms of $\varphi$, it seems like the numerator is $\frac 1{2\pi}e^{-x^2/2}$ times $\left[2\int_0^xe^{-t^2/2}dt\right][1-x^2]-[2x][e^{-x^2/2}]$ Now, obviously, twice the integral is between $0$ and $2x$ and $1-x^2\le e^{-x^2/2}$. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @fedja - thanks. I don't quite see the details in your statement. If you have an answer, could you please write it out in full detail? I've made a number of minor errors in trying to prove this, so verifying all details would help here.

Comment: Erm... Which Identity (or inequality) in my comment is unclear to you?

Comment: @fedja - I believe it checks out - thanks again. A minor point - in the outside factor, it should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$, is that correct? This doesn't change the conclusion, but I want to ensure the calcs make sense. Also what is an efficient way to prove $1 - x^{2} \leq e^{-x^{2} /2}$. I know $1 + x \leq e^{x}$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but can we get there directly from here? Or do we need to use calculus to formally prove it?

Comment: It is $(1/\sqrt{2\pi})^2=\frac 1{2\pi}$ (both $\varphi$ and $2\Phi-1$ have a factor of $\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ in them. If you know that $e^y\ge 1+y$ for all $y\in\mathbb R$, then just plug in $y=-x^2/2$.

Comment: @fedja - thanks again. For the inequality, I missed that $1 - x^{2} \leq 1 - \frac{x^{2}}{2} \leq e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$ (the first basic inequality), thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @fedja - could you please add this as an official answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Somehow [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1912478/305862)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1: to prove $G'(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$:**

*Here is a proof using* @fedja's *idea*:
(Actually, it is not difficult without using fedja's idea. But fedja's idea is better.):

We have $G(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$.
Let
$$f(x) := \ln G(x) = \ln x + \ln \phi(x) - \ln(2\Phi(x) - 1).$$

We have
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x} - x -  \frac{1}{2\Phi(x) - 1}\cdot 2\phi(x)
= \frac{1 - x^2}{x} - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}}{\int_0^x \mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm{d} t}$$
where we have used
$2\Phi(x) - 1 = 2 \int_0^x \phi(t)\, \mathrm{d} t$.

Using $\mathrm{e}^{-u} \ge 1 - u$ for all $u \ge 0$,
we have $\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2} \ge 1 - x^2/2 > 1 - x^2$ for all $x > 0$.
Also, we have $\int_0^x \mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm{d} t < \int_0^x 1 \,\mathrm{d} t = x$ for all $x > 0$. Thus, we have, for all $x > 0$,
$$f'(x) < \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}}{x} - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}}{x}  = 0.$$

Thus, we have $G'(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$.

**Dealing with $G'(x)$ for the case: $x = 0$:**

Now, let us deal with $x = 0$.
Since $\lim_{x\to 0} G(x) = 1/2$, we define $G(0) = 1/2$.
Using L'Hopital rule, we have
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{G(x) - G(0)}{x - 0} = 0$$
that is $G'(0) = 0$ (see Remarks at the end for details).

---

**Approach 2: to prove $G'(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$:**

We have $G(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$.
Let
$$f(x) := \ln G(x) = \ln x + \ln \phi(x) - \ln(2\Phi(x) - 1).$$

We have
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x} - x -  \frac{1}{2\Phi(x) - 1}\cdot 2\phi(x).$$

(1) If $x \ge 1$, we have $f'(x) < 1/x - x \le 0$.

(2) If $x\in (0, 1)$, let
$$g(x) := \frac{2\Phi(x) - 1}{1/x - x}f'(x) = 2\Phi(x) - 1 - \frac{x}{1 - x^2}\cdot 2\phi(x).$$
We have
$$g'(x) = 2\phi(x) - \frac{x^2 + 1}{(1 - x^2)^2}\cdot 2\phi(x) - \frac{x}{1 - x^2}\cdot 2\phi(x) \cdot (-x)
= - \frac{2x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}\cdot 2\phi(x) < 0.$$
Also, $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = 0$.
Thus, we have $g(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$.
Thus, we have $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$.

Thus, $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$.
Thus, $G'(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$.

---

***Remarks:* Dealing with $G'(x)$ for the case: $x = 0$:**:

We have
$$\frac{G(x) - G(0)}{x - 0} = 
\frac{\frac{x \phi(x)}{2 \Phi(x) - 1} - \frac12}{x}
= \frac{2x\phi(x) - (2\Phi(x) - 1)}{2x(2\Phi(x) - 1)}.$$
Let $N(x) := 2x\phi(x) - (2\Phi(x) - 1)$
and $D(x) := 2x(2\Phi(x) - 1)$.
We have
$$N'(x) = 2\phi(x) + 2x\phi'(x) - 2\phi(x) = 2x\phi'(x)$$
and
$$D'(x) = 2(2\Phi(x) - 1) + 2x \cdot 2\phi(x).$$
Note that $\lim_{x\to 0} N'(x) = 0$
and $\lim_{x\to 0} D'(x) = 0$.
We have
$$N''(x) = 2\phi'(x) + 2x\phi''(x)$$
and
$$D''(x) = 4\phi(x) + 4\phi(x) + 4x \phi'(x) = 8\phi(x) + 4x\phi'(x).$$
We have $\lim_{x\to 0} N''(x) = 0$
and $\lim_{x\to 0} D''(x) = \frac{8}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.
We have $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{N''(x)}{D''(x)} = 0$.
Using L'Hoptial rule, we have $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{N(x)}{D(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{N''(x)}{D''(x)} = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for this nice approach! Taking logs here does simplify things quite a bit. One follow up question. How do we deal with the case $x = 0$, i.e., to rigorously handle this point separately. Could you please add some details on this. I believe that $G^{\prime}(0) = 0$. Also what is the alternative to @fedja's idea? I would be interested to also learn this approach for my understanding.

Comment: @user4687531 You are welcome. I will edit some hours later.

Comment: Thanks again - this is great. Appreciate the additional details for my learning. One minor correction, in the first line of the alternative approach I believe you mean to write $G'(x) < 0$, i.e., the inequality sign is reversed, and should be changed.

Comment: @user4687531 Yes, typo is corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I've accepted your helpful answer. One thing, for the case $x = 0$, I didn't quite understand how L'Hospital's rule is used. Could you please expand some more details on that? I want to be able to apply such techniques rigorously myself going forward.

Comment: @user4687531 No problem. I will edit.

Comment: Thanks so much - that's very helpful indeed!

Comment: @user4687531 You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$G'(x)=-\frac 1{2\pi}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{  \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}\Bigg[\sqrt{2 \pi } e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \left(x^2-1\right)
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+2 x \Bigg]$$

Expanded as an infite series around $x=0$
$$\sqrt{2 \pi } e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \left(x^2-1\right)
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+2 x=$$ $$\sqrt \pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-(n+1)} \left(\frac{2}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (2 n+3)\right)}-\frac{1}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2} (2 n+5)\right)}\right)\,x^{2n+3}$$ All coefficients are positive.

So, for all $x>0$, $G'(x) <0$